# Protecting a php when page loaded with jQuery's .load function

Tags: php, jquery

My index page (index.php?profile=profilename_here) loads content into a div using jQuery's `load()` function in the normal fashion and all is working fine.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#details').load('pages/sidebar/details.php?profile=<?PHP echo $profile;?>').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

then in my pages/sidebar/details.php I have MySQL queries.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM public_profile WHERE username='$profile'") or die(mysql_error());
```

All the php stuff is secure and I am sanitising all varibales as I should be.... but if someone was to go to 'pages/sidebar/details.php?profile=' and change the profile name they will be bringing up other peoples details.

Is it possible to check if the page was loaded by `.load()` and if not, to stop the page from loading or scripts from executing?

Comment: Maybe you can use session so that your details.php would know if you're authenticated as the owner of the profile?

Comment: these are public pages and nobody has logged in to veiw these details

Comment: If the profiles are public and you don't have to be logged into see them, why does it matter if they pull up other profiles?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: it doesn't matter. i'm asking if there's a way of checking if it was loaded by jquery in the 1st place. the reason i'm asking is because any php includes i do i always define a varible and then check if it has been defined in the included pages. it just makes sense to me.

Comment: maybe this can shed some light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231789/is-ther-something-like-isset-of-php-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: @IanDitchfield It most certainly *does* matter if your concern is security.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to run code when the page is requested with ajax use

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') { 
    /* run this if requested by ajax */ 
}
```

unfortunately this doesn't make it much more secure since anybody can use dev-tools like firebug to change that URL in the code. If you want only want the current user to see their own profile you can store `$profile` in the `$_SESSION` that way they don't have direct access to the URL parameter.

Check out [OWASP's SQL Injection Prevention Cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for some methods to sanitize data, although I don't think anything there is PHP specific.

Comment: ok. thanks for your help. the code above was only added to explain my question. i'm pretty certain that i have the actual code sanitised and safe.

Comment: Just to be safe, I added a link to OWASP's SQL injection prevention cheatsheet, I'm sure it'll help somebody out...